# ListView basic example not working

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying one of the list view example given in my book, but even though I have followed the code line by line the method listView.setOnItemClickListener(this), is not working. Here is the code,

```
public class ViagemListActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listarViagens()));
                ListView listView = getListView();
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    private List<String> listarViagens() {
        return Arrays.asList("São Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Santa Catarina");

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterViewCompat<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            String mensagem = "Viagem selecionada: " + textView.getText();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mensagem,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, GastoListActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Please help,

Comment: Are Book's api version and your device's api version same ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `ListActivity` base class does not use an `OnItemClickListener` to indicate what is pressed (so you `implements OnItemClickListener` and override of `onItemClick` have no effect). Instead you need to override `onListItemClick()` (see documenation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)